# If one is aware the yetzer harah drove him to do something, must he stop?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, evil-inclination

Say you are fully aware that your yetzer harah drove you to do something specific- to visit a certain person on a certain day, or to have a certain kosher meal for dinner. Is that activitity necessarily something one must avoid doing, given its source?

Comment: What is your method for being fully aware that it's the Yetzer Harah?

Comment: The impulsivity of it, @Alex

Comment: What makes you think that impulsivity = Yetzer Harah?

Comment: Not all impulsivity, @Alex, but a certain kind of impusivity is pretty clearly yetzer harah

Comment: Why wouldn't you stop if you knew?

Comment: Well, do you have to, @Dude? The person you're visiting isn't an idol-worshipper, the food is permitted, do you need to stop just because the yetzer harah is behind it?

Comment: Of course. If you know your yetzer hara is trying to direct your actions a certain way then you don't listen. All your actions should be for heaven

Comment: That was my first thought, @Dude, but what about that midrash in which the yetzer harah gets trapped and the world essentially ceases functioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the activities you are performing are halachically acceptable, I see no formal obligation to stop (but see Ramban's [comment](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.2?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en) on Vayikra 19:2 - *naval b'reshut haTorah*).

However, if you feel the *yetzer hara* is driving you to those, you become conscious of the test you are facing: giving in or overcoming it. This is the "job" of the *yetzer hara*, to test you and allow you to gain credit by overcoming the challenge. See [Mesilat Yesharim](https://www.sefaria.org/Messilat_Yesharim.1.1?lang=bi) (starting with ch. 1)

> **The Holy One, blessed be He, has put man in a place where the factors which distance him from the blessed G-d are numerous.** These
>   are the physical lusts which if he is drawn after them, behold, he
>   draws away and goes ever further from the true good. **Thus, we see
>   that man is truly placed in the midst of a raging battlefield. For all
>   matters of this world, whether for the good or for the bad, are trials
>   for a man.** Poverty from one side versus wealth from the other. [...]
>
> If he will be a man of valor, emerging from the battle victorious on
>   all fronts - he will be the "Adam HaShalem" (whole/perfect man) who
>   will merit to cling to his Creator and will emerge from this corridor
>   to enter into the palace to enlighten in the Light of (eternal) Life.
>   **According to the extent that he conquered his inclination and lusts, and distanced from the factors which distance him from the good, and
>   exerted himself to cling to G-d, to that extent will he attain it and
>   rejoice in it.**

---

On the idea that the *yetzer hara* is actually a helper to help us improve, R Hillel Rotenberg (in [What's the purpose](http://a.co/bAKSVKp) p. 68) asks a powerful question on a gemara in [Sukkah 52a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.52a.4?lang=bi)

> Rabbi Yehuda taught: In the future, at the end of days, God will bring
>   the evil inclination and **slaughter** it in the presence of the righteous
>   and in the presence of the wicked. For the righteous the evil
>   inclination appears to them as a high mountain, and for the wicked it
>   appears to them as a mere strand of hair. These weep and those weep.
>   The righteous weep and say: How were we able to overcome so high a
>   mountain? And the wicked weep and say: How were we unable to overcome
>   this strand of hair?

Why does it say "slaughter"? Why not kill or eliminate? He answers that, after a cow is slaughtered, it still has a purpose. It changes its essence and moves from providing milk to providing meat.

Similarly, after God reveals himself to the world, the *yetzer hara* will still have a purpose. Everyone will understand at that time that its whole purpose was to entice man and see man stand up to the test. It acted only as a means for increasing our reward in the World to Come.

Comment: you hit the nail on the head- the hard part in this example is that the activities are halachically acceptable. The sources you cited are excellent resources for contemplating this matter. Todah rabah!